# Disable certain input element with javascript enabled

Tags: javascript, html, input

How do I disable  element so it will not submit when clicking on it (but make sure javascript events still work)? "Disabled" attribute turns javascript off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return false;` to the Javascript event handler.
(or `e.preventDefault(); e.returnValue = false;`)

Comment: I did this but there was no effect.

Comment: Oh it works now. The only thing I needed to figure out myself  was place a word return before the javascript function name in html attribute onClick.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to not make it a submit button

```
<input type="button" value="Button Text" onclick="myHandler()" />
```

Comment: The problem is my element is <IMG> and not a button.