# jquery htmlbox 4.0 plugin - how to disable the textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using htmlbox , I want to disble the text box in some cases ( so the user would not be able to write inside it).

how can i disable it?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: There are [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883651/disable-certain-input-element-with-javascript-enabled) [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372604/html-input-box-disable) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874688/how-to-disable-an-input-type-text-with-javascript) around, you can try to [search and adapt](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=html+disable+input) one of them.

Answer (score 1):

With the [disabled attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) (which has a matching boolean DOM property)

If you mean read only rather than actually disabled, then there is also [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-readonly).

Comment: Dorward: I tried that , but it did not work. I think it's because it's not a regular textarea but an htmlbox jquery plugin. so is there a way to disable the box?

Comment: The answer will probably be very specific to that plugin (which should have been mentioned in the original question and probably is too niche to ask outside of a specific support forum for that plugin). I know nothing about it.

Comment: I worte in my question that it is htmlbox 4.0. but thank's any way.

Comment: Ah. It *looked* like "A text input or textarea in HTML 4" filtered through bad English (which quite a lot of questions suffer from on this site). Beg pardon for the misunderstanding.